# numeric field overflow - which field exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In case of an error:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  numeric field overflow 
>   DETAIL:  A field with precision 2, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 1

How do I configure postgres or ruby/rails_4 pg library to tell me which field raises the error? Understandable error message will be:

> PG::Error: ERROR:  numeric field overflow.
>   Field "pressure", value "1111.12"

Comment: Rails is just repeating PostgreSQL's error message, which unfortunately doesn't have that information. From memory at the location within the code where that check is being made PostgreSQL does not have easy access to the context in which the numeric value is being used. It's certainly painful for debugging though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of PostgreSQL's error reporting and can not be configured with PostgreSQL, rails or the pg gem.